# Editing dataframes using loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

Suppose I have three dataframes:

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame({'X':[1,2,3]})
df_b = pd.DataFrame({'X':[1,2,3]})
df_c = pd.DataFrame({'X':[1,2,3]})
```

I want to do the following:

```
df_a['X'] = df_a.X+1
df_b['X'] = df_b.X+1
df_c['X'] = df_c.X+1
```

How can I do this using a loop, instead of separately for each dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following for instance:

```
import pandas as pd
df_a = pd.DataFrame({'X':[1,2,3]})
df_b = pd.DataFrame({'X':[1,2,3]})
df_c = pd.DataFrame({'X':[1,2,3]})

dfs = [df_a, df_b, df_c]
for df in dfs:
    df["X"] = df.X + 1
```

You could also use:

```
for c in ["a", "b", "c"]:
    tmp = globals()["df_{:}".format(c)]
    tmp["X"] = tmp.X + 1
```

Comment: Of course! I tried that but kept defining my list like this: `['df_a', 'df_b', 'df_c']`... Stupid XD Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame({'X': [1,2,3]})
df_b = pd.DataFrame({'X': [1,2,3]})
df_c = pd.DataFrame({'X': [1,2,3]})

frames = [df_a, df_b, df_c]
for frame in frames:
    frame['X'] = frame.X+1
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the input. This is basically the same as the first option provided by David S.

Comment: Sorry David S - you beat me to it!!